# showing the natural numbers exist from axioms (help with making sense of book)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm now on page 40 of a set theory book and I've hit the natural numbers. I think the book has oversimplified some things.

The successor of a set $x$ is defined to be $S(x)=x\cup\{x\}$

A set $I$ is inductive if:

- $0\in I$
- $n\in I\implies (n+1)\in I$ where $(n+1)=S(n)$ (it's just notational niceness)

The natural numbers are defined as follows:

$\mathbb{N}=\{x|x\in I \forall\text{ inductive sets }I\}$

APPARENTLY this leaves "the only remaining question: whether there are any inductive sets at all"

This leads to "the axiom of infinity: AN inductive set exists"

This is where I get confused, surely we have at least one inductive set already, we have axioms that state: there is an empty set, what makes sets equal, and the axiom of union, from the axiom of schema of comprehensions we can define inductiveness as a property surely

So I think we actually have one inductive set from the axioms already

Then Lemma 1.4 happens: "$\mathbb{N}$ is inductive, and if $I$ is any inductive set, then $\mathbb{N}\subset I$."

This I have a problem with.

### **My approach**

Right now we have a fixed definition of $S$, let us generalise this. (I see S functions as iterators really (programming terminology))

Lets consider $S_1=S\circ S$ ("even numbers") (I wanted to define the odd but you can "pretend 0" is the first odd, then it all follows.

I want to see a proof that "Any two (increasing) recursively defined sequences that do not converge and start at zero have an inductive set of points in common"

As without this only 0 would be in all inductive sets.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: The empty set and the axiom of union only give you finite sets, as you are only “allowed” to use the axioms finitely many times to create sets. Comprehensions only let you pick subsets of a set for a given property. None of this allows you to actually create an inductive set.

Can you clarify the lemma – does it say that, if there is an inductive set $I$ such that $ℕ ⊂ I$, then $ℕ$ is inductive, too?

Comment: How do we have one inductive set already?  From the axioms we have $\emptyset$, (which we call $0$), $s(\emptyset)$ (which we call $1$), $s(s(\emptyset))$ (which we call $2$) etc.  It does not automatically follow that there is some set which contains **all** of these.  What one would want to do is consider the sets $\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\ldots$, and take their union.  But what is the indexing set?  You cannot say $\mathbb{N}$, because that is not defined without  the axiom!

Comment: @k.stm the lemma says N is inductive. if I is any inductive set then N subset I" can you edit for me please, I'm on my phone now and it'd be painful to do it myself.

Comment: @TrevorRichards I don't see what you mean, why can't this be a property, why can't we have "inductive set" as a property, much like we have topologies (which is a set with a different property, or sigma-algebras)

Comment: @AlecTeal What do you mean when you say "property"?  Topologies are constructed, however as k.stm said above, you cannot construct something in infinitely many steps.  If you want to construct something infinite in finitely many steps, you have to know something infinite exists already (so that you can, for example, take the union over an infinite number of sets).

Comment: @TrevorRichards if I had my own complete understanding I would not have asked the questions, poking holes in what I have tried to construct is the opposite of helping, because I already know there are holes.

Comment: @AlecTeal What is your suggestion for the inductive set you get, something like $B = \{x; S(x) ∈ B\}$? This would be unrestricted comprehension (and I’m not sure this would be a ‘legal’ unrestricted comprehension either). You can only do *restricted comprehension*, that is something like $B = \{x; x ∈ A ∧ S(x) ∈ B\}$ for some set $A$ (and again I’m not sure if this is a legal comprehension – I know very little about axiomatic set theory). So what’s your set $A$? Or do you want to something entirely different? (Actually, I’m pretty certain these comprehensions are not legal.)

Comment: @AlecTeal I am sorry it felt like I was being negative or demeaning, that was not my intent.

Comment: @TrevorRichards I know, it's just I know there are holes in what i thought I knew, I've come here to be corrected, hopefully in an answer.

Comment: @k.stm read the comments addressed to Trevor please, finding more holes is not useful. I added previous thoughts to a question to show I was trying not "please show that this is a dead end, I don't feel I know this well enough yet" - I asked because I know I'm not understanding something. I've already found holes, I only need to find the one to know I've gone wrong.

Comment: @k.stm please don't give up though.

Comment: I understand that the ZF axiom of infinity is a equivalent to postulating the existence of at least one set that is Dedekind infinite. From such a set you can select a subset that satisfies the Peano axioms. For a formal proof, see the posting, "Daddy, where do numbers come from?" February 19, 2013 at my math blog at http://dcproof.wordpress.com/. It is not written in the language of ZFC, but you should be follow it. It may help you sort out the intricacies of the ZFC approach.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is very unclear to me what you’re asking, but I have a feeling, this might be your problem which you want to be resolved:

One might wonder how this lemma can possibly be true since there are so many sets on which you can perform induction – not only $ℕ_0$.

Intuitively one recognizes not only $ℕ_0 = \{0,1, 2, 3, …\}$, but also
$$\{0, 2, 4, …\} \quad\text{and}\quad \{0, 3, 6, 9, …\}$$
as *inductive* sets – probably because one is used to carry out inductions on such sets as well, not only on $ℕ_0$. One is inclined to think that these are inductive sets as well, just corresponding to $S^2$ and $S^3$ respectively.

But they are not. There is an issue to this:

> Inductive sets are explicitly just *defined* only for the successor function $S(n) = n ∪ \{n\}$ and not any other successor functions. The lemma just doesn’t make any statements about more generalized notions of inductive sets with e.g. $S^2$ or some other successor function $S'$. It doesn’t care.

If that’s your problem, think of it that way: An inductive set has to contain $0 = ∅$, and therefore $1 := 0 ∪ \{0\} = \{∅\}$, and therefore $2 := 1 ∪ \{1\} = \{∅,\{∅\}\}$, and so on. So it has to contain at least $ℕ_0 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, …\}$ as a subset. But this isn’t a proof, of course. The lemma just states that this is really true and that $ℕ_0$ itself is such an inductive set.

And if this isn’t your problem, I think you should clarify your question.

(By the way, I write $ℕ_0$ because $0$ is not a natural number.)

Comment: This has helped, certainly more than nothing, but I'm confused by the entire of what I posted, I've basically given you what the book says, I need my understanding corrected sufficiently to go "Oh, now I see why the definition of natural numbers makes sense" rather than just taking your (or the books) word for it.

Comment: @AlecTeal Okay, well, good luck with this then. That’s all of the time I’m investing in this question. I’m tired and I actually don’t have much time this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for trying I appreciate it